# VBA len function not passing length

Tags: vba, parameter-passing

I am trying to grab a cell check if it has decimal places and remove them then place a specific format in a cell depending on how many characters there are in the number, the len function returns null, and the instr function works but when passed to a variable returns null. Thank you to anyone who can help.  At the end of the first if function  I print the results of the 3 variables not working to the immediate window to verify, with the Debug.Print command please go to view menu and activate immediate window to watch.

```
Function cnvtDta()
    ActiveSheet.Select  
    Data1 = Range("data").Value  
    Dim rslt As String  
    rslt = Data1  
     Set myrng = Range("data")  
     Dim wot, sowot  


   'Find decimal place in cell   
    dot = myrng.Find(".", myrng)  
     If dot = True Then 
   'if decimal place strip remainders and decimal point  
     Dim pos, res  

             pos = InStr(1, rslt, ".")  
             res = Left(rslt, pos)  

               sowot = Len(res)  


   End If  
   Debug.Print res
   Debug.Print sowot
   Debug.Print pos
  'Return specific formats to cell  
   'thank you kindly to anyone who can spare the time to genuinely help
  End Function
```

Comment: Do not nest the ifs.

Comment: 1. Put Option Explicit on top of your module. 2. Try to declare all variable according to what they must be. `wot` variable has not been initialized.  3 I copied your starting code and declared `Dim myrng As Range, dot As Boolean, pos As Long, res As String, sowot As Long`. It works as expected...

Comment: `res` is wrongly calculated. You should simple use `sowot = Len(CStr(Int(rslt)))`. In your case it should be 'res = left(rslt, pos -1). It includes also the ending dot".". For such cases it is good to run the code line by line pressing F8 and see what values takes your variables. And use `If sowot = 2 Then  
        Data = Format(wot, "000##")  
    ElseIf sowot = 1 Then...`. Do not nest `If ... EndIf`. Use `ElseIf` or consecutive 'If  sowot = 1 Then Data = Format(wot, "0000#")1 (on the same row)

Comment: I ran by F8 dozens of times watched all variables in the immediate window dozens of times, nesting ifs might be relevant for python not VBA, I will try option explicit.

Comment: You put option explicit at the top of the code here it is a function there is no modules, however I will try.

Comment: Nested Ifs are COMPLETELE RELEVANT in VBA!  In your code, if sowot <> 2 nothing from inside the nest will be reached...

Comment: Very interesting.... And where this "functions" exist? It is a function only because you named it Function. It does not return anything. It can be anyhow a Sub without any problem, but this aspect is completely irrelevant... If you declare variables as I did, the beginning of the code will run as expected, returning the `sowot` variable.

Comment: The function exist at the very start where the key word function is, and to the other the if functions work I have tested them you do not understand how they work, the one and only problem is len string is not being passed toa variable, and inst is not being passed to a variable , thanks.

Comment: Adding option explicit made no difference contrary to your claim, which looked a bit suspect, when you said put it above module 2 when all option explicit have to go at the very top of all code on the whole modules, and it is a function there is no module 2?

Comment: @FaneDuru is correct about the nesting.

`If sowot = 2 Then  
'Stuff
If sowot = 1 Then`

The check for sowot = 1 will only fire if sowot = 2, which is of course contradictory.

Comment: I would like to kindly point out unless you are a MVP in excel in order to answer this you will have to run it, to do that in a cell in a sheet put 3.50, then to stop arguments, after the first end if, put Debug.Print res and Debug.Print  pos, I will edit my code to stop pointless arguments. And step through the code with F8. I genuinely sincerely send my gratitude to someone who can solve this, not stab in the dark and argue over nonsense.

Comment: You will have to name the cell with data ,'data' or change  the cell reference for it to work in the first instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically there's a couple of parts to your question.

1. Check if value has decimals. Here's one way to do it (based on values, not on strings)

```vb
Function DoesCellContainDecimals(inputRange As Range) As Boolean
    Dim tolerance As Double
    tolerance = 0.0001
    If Not IsNumeric(inputRange.Value2) Then
        'invalid argument
        DoesCellContainDecimals = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    If (Abs(Fix(inputRange.Value2) - inputRange.Value2) < tolerance) Then
        'value does not have meaningful decimals
        DoesCellContainDecimals = False
    Else
        'value has meaningful decimals
        DoesCellContainDecimals = True
    End If
End Function
```

2. Get the integer part of a number. There are two functions. Similar but different behavior with negative numbers (make sure if the value is a number first):

```vb
Int(6.5)  '6
Fix(6.5)  '6
Int(-6.5) '-7
Fix(-6.5) '-6
```

3. Format a number. Either turn it to string or set Range.NumberFormat property:

```vb
Format(6500000,"# ### ###") '6 500 000
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "# ### ##0" 'same effect as above but only when displaying in that cell.
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, interesting angle on checking for decimals, and removing, decimals, however I have the formatting part right I had to remove it because of pointless nit picking arguments, the format is actually leading zeros trailing numbers ,no rounding just integers, for e.g. "0000#", for 3.5 only extract 3 , and for 35.5 "000##" 35 no decimals no rounding , and so on. but you could not see that it was removed. It is for option pricing codes in spreadsheets.

Comment: Thanks for your thoroughness but there is no negative numbers involved merely the first part of option strikes from I believe Amazon and Apple the largest 4 figure numbers to single digit penny dreadfuls.

Comment: Sorry the code returns false whether there is decimals or trailing zeros, back to the drawing board, but you have given me some fresh ideas.

Comment: There was a bug - I changed the name when writing this. Forgot to change the result assignments. Glad you figured it out.